# Help with calculating the speed of a muon using change in muon flux and altitude

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics

I have been trying to calculate the speed of a muon using the change in muon flux and altitude using Lorentz transformations. This website explains the process with an example: [Example of Muon Experiment](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/muonex.html).
Unfortunately, this method isn't working with data from other sources like this graph:

[image]

This is the source for the graph: [Flux Variation of Cosmic Muons](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.0101.pdf)

It should yield a speed of about 99% the speed of light, but it is instead completely off. No matter which change in altitude and change in flux I use from this graph, I get an incorrect answer, and I don't know why. Is the data flawed or am I misunderstanding the math? Should I use a different method? I would greatly appreciate any help.

The example on the website has 2 muon fluxes of 422 and 550 muons per minute and a change in altitude of 1219. This is the solution:

[image]
[image]

Combining both steps, I got the equation:

[image]

Where h is the change in altitude, f is the flux corresponding to the lower altitude, and F is the flux corresponding to the higher altitude. This formula works for the values provided by the website, but doesn't work for any values I tried from the graph above such as a change in altitude of 441 m between the rightmost bar and the 2753 ft bar and the corresponding fluxes of about 2400 and 750. Thank you to anyone who can provide any help.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackexchange.

- Does the data fit the simple exponential you assume? The simple exponential is only right if all else is equal: atmospheric density the same, shielding the same, background level the same, etc. Also, the  interaction probabilities need to be negligible throughout.

That is unlikely to be the case for any real data across such a vast range of altitudes. Underground you will have shielding. Your background in your detector will be vastly different, since the hadronic component in cosmic rays varies with altitude, plus underground, there is radioactivity from the rock too. Depends on your detector whether that impacts the data or not.

Thus, let's approximate:

- Do you get a right-ish answer when you use only two neighboring numbers (e.g. at 338ft and 2753ft, etc.)?

Comment: The conditions in the experiment are supposedly the same according to the experimentors. Quote: "To test the flux dependence on elevation, the standardized detector modules were placed at several locations at different elevations, keeping the parameters of the detector units constant for all data collections. The data was taken at each elevation to determine muon flux per unit area per unit time. Our findings were checked for correlation against accepted flux vs. elevation trends."

Comment: Right. But did their detector truly only detect moons? At which level is it sensitive to backgrounds, in particular gammas....

Answer (score 0):

The data look quite strange to me. I assume -60 ft is underground, thus shielded and irrelevant. The huge difference between 2735 and 4200 ft tells me that something other than altitude is involved here, too.

Comment: Does this mean the data is incorrect because the report doesn't mention shielding. Here is a quote "To test the flux dependence on elevation, the
standardized detector modules were placed at several
locations at different elevations, keeping the
parameters of the detector units constant for all data
collections. The data was taken at each elevation to
determine muon flux per unit area per unit time. Our
findings were checked for correlation against accepted
flux vs. elevation trends.".

Comment: @Student That's a possibility. I have a silicon x-ray detector on my bench, also muon-sensitive. With x-rays blocked, the background changes noticeably if I just put a sheet of copper under it. That can't be blocking muons from the sky, it must be gamma rays from the ground. New England soil has a lot of thorium in it.